# How can I make my app run a terminal code when pushing button?

Tags: c++, c, macos

I was wondering how can I make a Push Button in OS X run a Terminal command when clicked.
the command is `networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`.

Comment: I suppose you don't want Xcode to run the command, but rather your app. Also, which language? Tagging with C and C++ simultaneously is usually meaningless and wrong.

Comment: Set an onClick event listener that will `exec` the command when called. As for making the button, not sure too much on Mac. Could look at Qt

Comment: Where do you want to push the button?

Comment: I don't care what language, Answer with the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

If your coding in an objective-c project option for mac osx in xcode, you can just throw in a system("Arg"); command inside an IBaction. You can mix c code inside objective-c projects without any effort.

system("networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4");

Answer (score 0):

I've used [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html) in the past to run shell commands in objective-c. It may or may not be useful to you.

I'll even link a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36537/nstask-tutorial)

This is assuming you have a button setup to use either an IBAction or a target/action pair.